# How to save the results analysed by the Chrome's Coverage tool?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

At a first glance it looks like very useful tool,  however I cannot find any operation like `Save` or similar option.

[image]

Does anyone know whether it is possible to save the results analysed by the  Chrome's Coverage tool? Thanks

Comment: I don't know why this is closed.  It seems pretty obvious that we would want some type of output that indicates what is and isn't being used in a particular document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Devtools Coverage: how to save or capture code used code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106841/chrome-devtools-coverage-how-to-save-or-capture-code-used-code)

Comment: It's not currently possible, but there's a bug report for it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717195

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo how is this duplicate if this question has been asked earlier when the one in your link? :) I should say the other question should be marked as duplicate of this one :))

Comment: @Morpheus yep you're right. that one 1 month newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned int the comments above, and in the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106841/chrome-devtools-coverage-how-to-save-or-capture-code-used-code), a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717195) has been filed for this.

In the meanwhile, as stated in the [comments section of this page](https://www.gideonpyzer.com/blog/runtime-coverage-using-chrome-devtools/), one can use `CoverageRange`, `FunctionCoverage` or `ScriptCoverage` to gather the same data via [Chrome's RDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Profiler/#type-ScriptCoverage).